# How can I replace an image with another image in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Tags: content, picture-collage-maker-pro

I use [Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) on Windows 10 to make a collage. I have an image in the collage, which I'd like to replace with another image. In Photoshop 23.5.1, I would right-click on the image in the layer section, then `Replace Contents`:

[image: 1]

How can I replace an image with another image in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the GUI. However, the `.pwp` project files ([Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) project files) are XML files, and one can easily change the file path of a picture. Alternatively, one can change the file of the picture itself.

The file path of the picture depends on whether the following option is checked:

[image]